# Changing installation directory of installed DB2 in AIX 7.1

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I have installed DB2 10.1 in AIX 7.1 at /opt/IBM/db2/V10.1. But there is a script which is expecting DB2 at /opt/db2_10_1.

I am not sure if it is possible to change the directory of an installed software and if I do it, what are the points I have to keep in my mind before performing this step.

FYI- I am not an AIX or DB2 expert. I am just performing this task as instructed.

Comment: Don't do that. Just create a symlink: `ln -s /opt/IBM/db2/V10.1 /opt/db2_10_1`

Comment: what is the best way to _undo_ the above command and bring it back as it was earlier?

Comment: It is `rm /opt/db2_10_1` But you should rather ask your system-administrator for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did your instructions specify a non-default path for the Db2-installation?
(The path /opt/IBM/db2/V10.1 is a typical default for AIX )

Do not manually hack to change the installation directory of Db2, just because a script is badly written! Responsible admins would never allow such mistakes on production environments.

It is an error for a script to hard-code a Db2-installation path. That script should be coded correctly to *determine* the Db2-installation path, or to have that information provided via configuration or arguments.

A possible option is to create a symbolic link so that /opt/db2_10_1 points to the real path at /opt/IBM/db2/V10.1 , but this is not guaranteed to work for all situations, it depends on how badly written is the script - so other different errors may appear later from that script (although Db2 itself will function normally).

A separate matter is that it is unwise to install a Db2 version that is already out of support (end of life).  Does the business understand the consequences of installing an out-of-support version? (unless the business has purchased an extended support contract from IBM).

Comment: yes, the instruction specify a non-default path for DB2 installation and there are many more instruction which expect the same location. 
As per you suggestion, I'll not play with it manually. 
I am testing the application in DB2 10.1 because it needs to be deployed in such env. How they are handling out-of-support application is out of my scope. But, testing need to be done as per the production env.

Answer (score 0):

- You have to make new install
- stop instance
- rename sqllib directory
- recreate instance using db2icrt in new binaries in install directory
- import catalogued database with db2cfimp previously exported using db2cfexp